# How can i remove a substring using regexp in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Given a file containing multiple strings (one in each line) - among them there will be the following two strings:

```
de12_QA_IR_OS_HV
de12_IR_OS_HV
```

(the only difference is "QA_" in the right position).

I need to perform some action if the current line being handled contains one of the above.
if yes, i should use the string value without the "QA_" substring.

I am using the following regexp to detect the values `/de12_(QA_)?IR_OS_HV/` but is there a way to remove the "QA_" if it exist using the same regexp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture what's before and after the QA_:

```
if (/(de12_)(QA_)?(IR_OS_HV)/) {
    print $1 . $3, "\n";
```

Or, use substitution

```
if (s/de12_(QA_)?IR_OS_HV/de12_IR_OS_HV/) {
    print $_, "\n";
}
```

But, in fact, you know what string to use if you the regex matches:

```
if (/de12_(QA_)?IR_OS_HV/) {
    print "de12_IR_OS_HV\n";
}
```

Comment: Your last edit is right :) only if it was the only case... the input file contains many pairs of strings (having the "QA_" in one of them), and i tried to get a general way of handling them. Now i need to create a sub to handle all cases. Anyhow, your answer helped me...

Comment: @NirMH: repeat after me: "choroba has always the good answer". (note: you can do the same with Miller)